# CakePHP: when using Translatable behavior, how to make English as the fallback language?

Tags: cakephp, translation

when a certain entry in a table has no translation, is it possible to display the default/english translation instead? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [patch](http://codaset.com/robwilkerson/scratchpad/source/master/blob/cakephp/behaviors/translatable.php) to do this very thing a while back. It's only been lightly tested, but it's available in my "Scratchpad" project in Codaset. The fact that it's only lightly tested is the reason it's in the Scratchpad project rather than a project of its own.

Unless/until the patch is applied to core, I just copied the file (renaming the behavior `Translatable` and use it from within my `app/models/behaviors/` directory. A [README](http://codaset.com/robwilkerson/scratchpad/source) file is also available that discusses the modified behavior.

Let me know if it helps you. Feel free to enter bugs, etc. As I said, it's only lightly tested, so YMMV and, of course, no warranty is given or implied. :-)